# Is there any way to implement method based access restrictions in acegi-0.5 plugin in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am looking for syntax like `@Secured(["USER_ROLE"])` for Acegi-0.5 plugin in Grails.

At the moment I have to go and put restrictions manually one by one on every method that needs access restriction on my app.

Please Note: I have to use grails-1.2.3 version

Comment: or do i have to use requestMapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... I simply migrated the acegi security to spring security and all those method based mapping started to work...